# Physics movement for unity 2D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a player on XY position. After player's swipe position must be increased or decreased on 1 for x-area. Tryed to do this by ***addForce*** and ***velocity***, but these ways are increasing x-area pos to infinity.
So - How i can stop increasing after then position will be (1,0) after (0,0)? or mb anything else method can help me?

```
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (Input.touchCount > 0)
        {
            theTouch = Input.GetTouch(0);

            if (theTouch.phase == TouchPhase.Began)
            {
                theTouchStartPos = theTouch.position;   
            }

            if (theTouch.phase == TouchPhase.Ended)
            {
                theTouchEndPos = theTouch.position;     

                if (theTouchEndPos.x <= theTouchStartPos.x)
                {
                    Debug.Log("swipe left");
                    Move(Vector2.left);
                }

                if (theTouchEndPos.x >= theTouchStartPos.x)
                {
                    Debug.Log("swipe right");
                    Move(Vector2.right);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    void Move(Vector2 direction)
    {
        //playerRb.velocity = new Vector2(direction.x, direction.y) * speed;
        float step = speed * Time.deltaTime;
        playerPos = Vector2.Lerp(playerPos, playerPos + direction, step);
    }
```

Comment: what do you mean by "x-area"

Comment: You assign a value `playerPos` but I don't see where you are using it anywhere ...

Comment: @Charly sorry for my bad english :(
i mean coordinate system

Comment: @derHugo its my last try to do a normal movement

Comment: do you really have to animate it?  can you just change the position ?

Comment: @Fattie i could, but wanted to understand moment what i asked in this topic :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So it sounds like what you are trying to achieve is: Each swipe moves your player one "step" to left or right on the X-axis but smoothly.

In your current approach you call the `Lerp` only in one single frame when the touch ends so the object will barely move at all.

I would rather set the target x-axis position and let the playeroventowards that with the given speed in every physics update call.

As [SpicyCatGames pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68126262/7111561) correctly, you should always separate the handling of User Input (`Update`) from the physics (`FixedUpdate`).

```
private float targetX;

private void Awake ()
{
    targetX = playerRb.position.x;
}

void FixedUpdate()
{
    // Move the player towards the target position but only on X
    // -> keep the Y velocity
    var position = playerRb.position;
    position.x = Mathf.MoveTowards(position.x, targetX, speed * Time.deltaTime);
    playerRb.MovePosition(position);
}

private void Update ()
{        
    if (Input.touchCount > 0)
    {
        theTouch = Input.GetTouch(0);

        if (theTouch.phase == TouchPhase.Began)
        {
            theTouchStartPos = theTouch.position;   
        }
        else if (theTouch.phase == TouchPhase.Ended)
        {
            theTouchEndPos = theTouch.position;     

            if (theTouchEndPos.x < theTouchStartPos.x)
            {
                Debug.Log("swipe left");
                Move(-1);
            }
            else if (theTouchEndPos.x > theTouchStartPos.x)
            {
                Debug.Log("swipe right");
                Move(1);
            }
        }
    }
}

void Move(float direction)
{
    targetX += direction;
}
```

Comment: Very appreciate your help! One more question - we are using time.deltaTime, why not fixedDeltaTime?

Comment: @perezvonish' if you look into the ApI of [`deltaTime`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-deltaTime.html) you will find `When this is called from inside MonoBehaviour.FixedUpdate, it returns Time.fixedDeltaTime.` so it doesn't really matter ;)

Comment: @derHugo 10-4 Captain :)

Comment: @perezvonish' Time.fixedDeltaTime is only for setting the value, it will stay at the target  time you set, but your computer can't actually precisely process each physics update in that exact amount of time. Time.deltaTime will give you the real value which may vary slightly.

Comment: @derHugo does this code actually work? It shouldn't in all cases. FixedUpdate might skip the frame where your touch was actually in Begin phase. Same with GetKeyDown, using fixedUpdate will sometimes cause it to skip the frame where the key was pressed down, since that exists for only one frame and you're not guaranteed to have a fixedUpdate for every Update.

Comment: @SpicyCatGames oh yes, thanks for pointing that out! You should usually always separate the input logic from the physics, you're absolutely right. Now it should work ;)

Answer (score 0):

Do not take single frame inputs such as `TouchPhase.Began` or `GetKeyDown` in `FixedUpdate()`. It may work on your machine but it will not register the input every time on a faster machine.

> "FixedUpdate is often called more frequently than Update. It can be called multiple times per frame, if the frame rate is low and **it may not be called between frames at all if the frame rate is high**." - https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ExecutionOrder.html

What this means is that `FixedUpdate` is not guaranteed to run on the frame when you pressed down, so inputs that only last for one frame such as `TouchPhase.Began` or `GetKeyDown` may not register if the framerate is high enough.

It's surprising to me how noone else noticed this.

Comment: Final sentence - I wrote a whole answer about this, heh !

Answer (score -1):

This seems to get discussed a lot.

**FixedUpdate** is for physics *"calculations"*.

If you are animating something - that is to, say, you want to draw something each time the scene is drawn (perhaps changing the position) - you very much use Update, not FixedUpdate.

It's both pointless (and inaccurate) to change the position of on object on the FixedUpdate calls.

Say this represents time and the F are fixed update events and the D (draw) are update events

```
F  F  F    F F  F F  F  F   F  F  F  F F  F F  F 
 D       D           D  D       D         D
```

You (of course, obviously) only need to set the position of the object when you are about to draw it.

And indeed, when you're about to draw it: you (obviously) want the position it should be in at that actual time.

(The script given here shows "F" and "D" running .. https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.FixedUpdate.html )

As it explains in the documentation, FixedUpdate is for physics >>calculations<<.  So, if you are extending the physics engine, simulating something, applying the precise rules of a bullet game, or whatever.  (I've rarely had to use it.)  Note that interestingly, if for some reason you were calculating a planet or something and doing that every FixedUpdate, you'd *still* have to actually set the position of the planet (or whatever it is) at the exact moment when you're about to draw it!  (ie in Update.)

---

It's another good example of the famously touchy Unity doco.  In dozens of places they show something being moved (ie, using Update, when the draw happens).  On that FixedUpdate page it very confusingly just mentions physics "calculations" which is very vague.  If they had added a couple more words *("for behind the scenes physics calculations where you are not actually getting the position to draw something that's about to be drawn")* it would all be clearer!

Comment: `It's both pointless (and inaccurate) to change the position of on object on the FixedUpdate calls` .. yes it would if you do it via the `transform` component ... Not, if you use the `Rigidbody`/`Rigidbody2D` component which as you say yourself belong to Physics so you should update their values in `FixedUpdate`

Comment: see [`Rigidbody.MovePosition`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.MovePosition.html) `Rigidbody.MovePosition moves a Rigidbody and complies with the interpolation settings. When Rigidbody interpolation is enabled, Rigidbody.MovePosition creates a smooth transition between frames. Unity moves a Rigidbody in each FixedUpdate call.`

Comment: Changing the position in `Update` would actually rather break the physics and anything related to it like collision detection and mentioned interpolation since it is actually only applied in `FixedUpdate` even if you apply `Rigidbody.position` within `Update`

Comment: yff, thanks for information!
in my defense of "why i used it in Update, not in Fixed" i can say - when i cheked my question about "why player can enter in other gameObj's collider" saw a lot of topics about drawing in FixedUpdate.

Comment: @perezvonish' there is a huge amount of total nonsense on the WW about Unity, so take care!

Comment: ? in the question, the OP is setting the position - as you usually do when you indeed "animating" something.  it's not a physics simulation, it's an animation move